# How to create Azure Container SAS from Stored Access Policy in Python

Tags: python, azure, permissions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a **SAS** with python code and use it to create a ContainerClient with only "write" permissions to upload data to one specific container.
I was trying several code snippets but couldn't find anything suitable, only the following code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import generate_container_sas
    
generate_container_sas(account_name="<yourAccountName>",container_name = "<yourContainerName>",account_key="<yourAccountKey>" ,policy_id='<yourPolicyId>')
```

**Problem:** I don't want to give the user an account_key or delegation_key, but at least one of those is required for this function.
Is there a way to create a SAS only using account_name, container_name and policy_id?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks:).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

The `account_name` and `account_key` are needed when creating sas token. `Account_key` is used to authenticate. Without it, the request to storage will be denied.

Regarding [Stored Access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/define-stored-access-policy), it's used to set the `start time`, `expiry time`, or `permissions`(like read/write) for a sas token. It's nothing to do with the authentication.